# How to search by object with nested object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to filter my orders collection by search object. want to show only matching order in view.

I have **orders** array collection like:

```
$scope.orders = [{ 
    "_id" : "56461e2b7caaf49345076709", 
    "customer" : {"_id": "76461e2b7caaf49345076a19b", "name": "cr1"},
    "seller" : {"_id": "96461e2b7caaf49345076a18b", "name": "sl1"}, 
    "address" : "Squire Park",
    "qt" : 5
},
{ 
    "_id" : "56461e2b7caaf49345076708", 
    "customer" : {"_id": "76461e2b7caaf49345076a19b1", "name": "cr2"},
    "seller" : {"_id": "96461e2b7caaf49345076a18c1", "name": "sl2"}, 
    "address" : "Squire Park1", 
    "qt" : 6
},
..................
];
```

and my **search** object like:

```
$scope.search = {
    "qt": 5,
    "customer" : {"_id": "76461e2b7caaf49345076a19b1"},
    "seller" : {"_id": "96461e2b7caaf49345076a18c1"}
};
```

view:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="order in orders | myFilter:search">
      <td>{{order._id}}</td>
      <td>{{order.customer.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

What should be my **myFilter** function?

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple solution would be attaching a filter function to the scope

```
$scope.orderFilter = function(order) {
  // implementation depends on how you want the search to behave
  // for example, if the order should match every property of the searchObj
  var pass = true;
  for (var property in $scope.search) {
    if ($scope.search.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if($scope.search[property] != order[property]) {
        pass = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return pass;
  // .. though i wouldnt recommend this implementation
  // you´d be better off by implementing a more specific matching
}
```

And in the view

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:orderFilter">
  <td>{{order._id}}</td>
  <td>{{order.customer.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

---

If you want the filter-expression you are using to work, you have to register a custom filter on your module. This would be done like so:

```
angular.module('app').filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(orders, searchObj) {
    var filteredOrders = [];
    orders.forEach(function(order) {
      // evaluate if you want to have the order show up based on the searchOjb
      // .. if so, add it to the array like so:
      filteredOrders.push(order);
    });
    return filteredOrders;
  }
});
```

**NOTE**

If you change a property of you search object, your filter function wont be called again, because angular filters arent listening for changes of nested properties. The filter will only be called if you change the whole search object.